# TLS-SRP support in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, jsse

I want to develop Java client which can communicate with TLS-SRP server implemented in C and GnuTLS. I fond that JSSE does not support TLS-SRP and Bouncy Castle has too little documentation which can be useful. Is there any information how I can develop java client with TLS-SRP?

Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

I recently got interested in utilizing SRP as well.  I haven't started working on it "yet," but [Nimbus SRP](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-srp) looks promising, and the [Stanford Page](http://srp.stanford.edu/links.html) on SRP had some good resources.

Comment: There is also a [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/srpforjava/) project for SRP in Java which may be worth looking at.

Comment: link to Nimbus SRP seems to be dead!

Comment: Good catch, updated.